# I want to buy a new cpu

Tags: gaming

I want play pubg mobile on pc at 60 fps and smoothly without any lag. I think to buy an 8 Gb ram cpu with 1 Tb memory and I am confused which processor and graphics card to buy for comlplete 60 fps gaming but I want to buy the cpu under ₹ 30000 or $ 450.

Comment: This is far too broad for us to answer. What motherboard do you have? What games and applications will you be running? Anything else we should know about your system/upgrades?

Answer (score 1):

Get :
Ryzen 5 1600
B450 Motherboard (Probably from ASROCK or anything with beafy VRMs)
16GB DDR4 3000Mhz (You can probably overlock them)
Radeon 580 or GTX 1060 (Or something similar)
Get a 128GB SSD (Boot Drive) and a 1TB HDD

That should be pretty much it. Not sure tho.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics card is what will help you to play the game without problems.
For CPUs you can consider:

- AMD 2600X
- i5 8600K

But you also want a strong GPU, at least a GTX 1060.

Comment: I wonder why would you want to go for 2600x instead of 1600x ?

Comment: @SagnikPradhan Why go one generation back when OP has the budget to get the latest generation of CPUs? Not saying that the 1600X is no slouch either, even in 2018

Comment: Mmm Cause 1600x performs similar to 2600x but it is a whole lot cheaper. Plus 2600x series are APUs But he already has a Dedicated GPU So why would he need the extra vega cores ?

Comment: 2600X is NOT an APU. And it is newer, better, and the TS can afford it. The price difference is small compared to 1600X, so why not.